# SQL Server 2008 - connection to the SQL Server Database File

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Developer edition. In visual studio, when I want to add new data connection in server explorer (sql database file) I'm getting the following error message:

[alt text http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/6151/errorum.jpg](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/6151/errorum.jpg)

I don't get errors when I chose *Microsoft SQL Server* as DataSource.

SQL Server allows remote connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching directly to a .MDF file works **only** with SQL Server **Express** edition. It's a Express-only feature.

For the Developer edition, you need to attach the MDF to your Developer server (using SQL Server Management Studio) and thus pick it from the server's list of databases.

Comment: I can't believe that developer edition lack some of the express edition features :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the connection options in VS2008.

Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Data Connections and change the SQL Server Instance name

I had problems with this when having SQL2k5 and 2K8 installed

Answer (score -1):

Please check:

1
  Has the Sql server started?

> using Sql Server Configuration Manager

2.

Has you enabled the server to allow remote connection?

> Right click on the server name ==>
>   properties ==> Connections==> Enable
>   remote connection.